# Changing network mode to N only in OpenWRT

Tags: openwrt

My new router (TP-Link TL-WR841N/ND v9) doesn't have a dd-wrt build, so I switched to OpenWRT. I didn't see any options under the network/wireless settings to change my network mode to N-only (it's currently mixed mode b/g/n).

Am I just missing something obvious, or is there a way to do this?

- Firmware Version: OpenWrt Barrier Breaker 14.07 / LuCI Trunk (0.12+svn-r10530)
- Kernel version: 3.10.49

**Edit:** Based on [the documentation](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/wireless#common.options), it seems that I need to set the `require_mode` parameter in the `/etc/config/wireless` file. Is it possible to set it through the LuCI web interface?

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to OpenWRT from dd-wrt as well, but as far as I can tell, the LuCI interface only covers many features to make the router usable and do fancy routing, it doesn't include everything. There is probably a simple way of opening the config files and editing them, but I've forgotten how to navigate to them in PuTTY so I'm doing things the command line way:

logging in via Telnet or PuTTY isn't hard, just put the router's address in and use the normal user/pass combo when prompted.

Once in, I tried typing:

```
uci set wireless.radio$.require_mode=A      #where $ is the relevant radio's number,      
                                            #probably 0 but it was a 1 in my case.
                                            #and A is the setting you want (n for you)
uci commit                                  #commits settings
wifi                                        #i think this resets the wifi module
```

You can then verify this setting by typing:

```
uci get wireless.radio$.require_mode        #again, your $ may vary
```

Bam! You did it.